# Convergence of $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I was supposed to calculate integral
$$
I=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$

My teacher gave my following solution:
$$
I=\sum_{i=-2}^1 \int_{\frac{i}{2}}^{\frac{i+1}{2}} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
and for example:
$$
\forall _{x\in(0;\frac{1}{2}]} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\geq\frac{1}{x}>0
$$
therefore:
$$
I_3=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
is divergent, so $I$ is divergent.

Is this a valid solution? Proving that one of the fragments of the integral is divergent implies that the whole integral is divergent? I think it's an odd function, and since the integration intervals are symmetrical, then the integral should be convergent and equal $0$.

Comment: its mad lousy but hey it works!

Comment: you cannot apply symmetry argument because the function is discontinuous on the interval

Comment: @ILoveMath Even if the discontinuity is symmetrical too? And for the first part of my question - is checking only one part of the integral and proving that it is divergent is sufficient for the whole integral to be divergent?

Comment: Yes, one part diverging is enough to conclude that the integral diverges. However, one can interpret it as a principal value integral, and as such it has a value, and the value is indeed $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh, thank you, I didn't know about such property. No, I wasn't supposed to calculate principial value.

Comment: @MartinYakuza Principle value isn't typically taught in introductory integral calculus.

Comment: Also your teacher has unconventional notation.

Comment: @Chickenmancer why is this notation unconventional? In different countries there might be slightly different notations.

Comment: its just lousy thats all

Comment: @ILoveMath but what's lousy in that excatly?

Comment: because in the domain of the integral, the function has 3 discontinuities, so ideally one should break up the integral in three pieces and see divergence in at least one of them. Your teachers way is hand weavy and it may be risky, it is just lousy overall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not apply symmetric arguments as the domain of integration contains three points where the function has discontinuities, specifically at x=-1,0,1. Ideally, the first step in solving these improper integrals is to break it in three different pieces with each domain containing one of the discontinuities, and then study each integral separately. If one can find that one of the integrals diverge, then the entire integral surely diverge.

As was pointed out in the comments, you teacher's solution employs unconventional notation, but, in fact, it is not about the notation, but the procedure. I believe theres no need to break the integrals in 5 pieces, and the show through a lousy argument that one of the pieces diverges thus the entire integral diverges. It is just a hand-weavy way to do things, that I believe it may be great to teach when you already know the material well and you can allow certain sloppiness, but if you are a beginner, youre better off learning it the correct way and not the slick way

Comment: about the notation: there were only 4 pieces originally (-1,-1/2),(-1/2,0),(0,1/2),(1/2,2), I wrote the sum limit as $2$ instead of $1$ by mistake, I have corrected it in my question